# VBA code for Single filter in Pivot Table

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to VBA ... I'm trying to create a single filter

Under the Transaction Type, I want to filter out "Payment"

Below is my code but when it gets to pf.Current page ="Payment" it error out.

```
Sub

Dim pf As PivotField

Set pf = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("GENERIC TRANSACTION DETAIL").PivotFields( _
"transaction type")

pf.CurrentPage = "payment"

End Sub
```

Thank you for any feedback

Comment: Is "transaction type" a page field? The [CurrentPage property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197857.aspx) is only valid for page fields. Also, the Sub needs to have a name - just using `Sub` on its own won't even compile

Answer (score 0):

Your `"transaction type"` might not be a page field as mentioned by Debosmit Ray.
You can use the flowing code to do a single item filter.

```
Sub SingleFilter()
    Dim item As PivotItem
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("GENERIC TRANSACTION DETAIL").PivotFields("transaction type")
        .ClearAllFilters
        For Each item In .PivotItems
            If Not item.Name <> "payment" Then
                item.Visible = False
            End If
        Next item
    End With
End Sub
```